# Set Reflection Property object without knowing the property name & value

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class named `BackUp` that contains a few properties.
Let's say I have an existing instance of `BackUp` with its properties initialized.

As I use reflection in the `BackUp` class where I want to create an `AgentActivator` object and I need to set its properties, the idea is to retrieve the properties from the `BackUp` object.

The problem is to take `PropertyInfo` object from the `BackUp` object and set the matching property on the reflected object.

I am doing the following:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(localBackUp.AssemblyFileName);
Type currentClasstype = assembly.GetType(localBackUp.ClassName);            
PropertyInfo[] properties = currentClasstype.GetProperties();
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(localBackUp.AssemblyFileName, 
    localBackUp.ClassName);
string propName= null;                   
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in properties)
{
    propName= prop.Name;
    currentClasstype.GetProperty(propName).
        SetValue(classInstance, findProperty(localBackUp, propNmae), null);

}
```

I need to find a way to implement the `findProperty` Method.
Its job is to get the string (property name) and return the matching value from the `localBackUp` which holds property with the `propName`.

Comment: You'd better first fix all those typos… Then you can hope for someone to deciper your code.

Comment: Also, when you already know how to call `SetValue` you sure will figure out how to call `GetValue`.

Comment: I tried to fix the grammar without changing the meaning of your sentences. Not sure if I successed, so apologizes in advance if that's not the case.

Comment: Since you are already showing GetProperty usage, I'm unclear where the problem is - can you clarify we're you are stuck?

Comment: How does `localBackup` store the property information? In a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

From your code I assume that `Type` of `localBackup` and `classInstance` is the same and thus are just initializing a new class instance with the same property values another class instance (`localBackup`) already has try

```
prop.GetSetMethod().Invoke (classInstance, new object[] { prop.GetGetMethod().Invoke(localBackUp, null) } );
```

One remark though:

IF my assumption is true then there are IMHO much better options to do what you are trying (for example by serializing and deserializing an instance)...

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is clone the object, the best (I think) approach is described here: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp/78612#78612) (as @Yahia mentioned serialize and deserialize). Quite important is that it returns *deep copy*, so original and new object don't *share* data between itself.